# How to replace empty values in one column with modified values from another column?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following dataframe called `mapping_df`:

```
mapping | store_id
--------|---------
   a    |    1
   b    |    2
        |    3
   c    |    4
        |    5
```

I would like to modify it so that I can have

```
mapping | store_id
--------|---------
   a    |    1
   b    |    2
 edit-3 |    3
   c    |    4
 edit-5 |    5
```

I have the following code, but I'm not sure if its using Pandas to its full potential

```
for idx, value in mapping_df["mapping"].iteritems():
    if not value:
        mapping_df["mapping"].iloc[idx] = "edit-{}".format(mapping_df["store_id"].iloc[idx])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this guy:

```
df['mapping'] = df[['mapping', 'store_id']].apply(lambda x: x[0] if x[0] else 'edit-%d' % x[1], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the blank entries in the mapping column are `NaN` rather than just empty strings, the you could use the `combine_first()` method:

```
df.mapping = df.mapping.combine_first('edit-' + df.store_id.astype(str))
```

Comment: yeah, unfortunately they are empty strings :(