# Fill blank cells with another column value in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to test if cells in column `C` are blank, if yes, fill it with value in column `A`, if `A` is `NaN`, fill it with `B`. Column `C` may have some blank cells look as below:

`df`:

```
    A             B               C 
0   xyz           NaN             12.03.2010    
1   abc           NaN             01.10.2009
2   NaN           14.11.2010      
3   02.10.2010    NaN
```

`C` seem to have some blank cells but as I test with `df.iloc[2, 2] == None` or `pd.isnull(df.iloc[2, 2])`, both returned `False`. Why this happened? How can we test if it's truly blank?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace empty values in one column with modified values from another column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899835/how-to-replace-empty-values-in-one-column-with-modified-values-from-another-colu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) the empty strings with `nan` and then chain a couple [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```py
df.C = df.C.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True).fillna(df.A).fillna(df.B)

#             A           B           C
# 0         xyz         NaN  12.03.2010
# 1         abc         NaN  01.10.2009
# 2         NaN  14.11.2010  14.11.2010
# 3  02.10.2010         NaN  02.10.2010
```

Alternatively start with `str.strip()` to make the replacement simpler:

```py
df.C = df.C.str.strip().replace('', np.nan).fillna(df.A).fillna(df.B)
```

Comment: Hi tdy, thanks for the answer. I applied the code to more data and looks like it only replaced some rows and not the rest. Any idea?

Comment: @nilsinelabore try changing the regex to `r'^\s*$'` (answer updated)

Comment: or avoid a regex entirely by starting with `str.strip()` (added to answer)

Comment: What does `^\s*$` mean?

Comment: @nilsinelabore `^` means beginning of string, `$` means end of string, and `\s*` means 0 or more whitespace, so the whole regex means "strings that are totally empty or only contain whitespace"

Answer (score 1):

Another way;
.

**conditions**

1. `(df['C']=='')& (df['A'].isna())` - if `C` is blank and `A` is NaN
2. `(df['C']=='')& (df['A'].notna()` - IF C is blank and `A` is not NaN

**Solution**

1. If condition `1.` is met solution is `B`
2. If condition `2.` is met solution is `A`
3. Alternative solution if neither `1` nor `2` occurs is keep `C`

**Implement using;**
Use `np.select(conditions, solutions, alternative)`

Let us now put itin code. See Code below

```
conditions=[(df['C']=='')& (df['A'].isna()),(df['C']=='')& (df['A'].notna())]

solution=[df['B'],df['A']]
```

**Code**

```
 df['C']=np.select(c,sol, df['C'])
```

**Outcome**

```
          A           B           C
0         xyz         NaN  12.03.2010
1         abc         NaN  01.10.2009
2         NaN  14.11.2010  14.11.2010
3  02.10.2010         NaN  02.10.2010
```

Comment: Hi wwnde, thanks for the answer. Do you mind adding some comments to your solution for better understanding?

Comment: See my edits above. Happy to explain further if needed

Answer (score 1):

This happened because the missing values in the dataframe may be empty strings "", and NaN is a different value in terms of a Pandas dataframe. So the equality check should be testing whether a cell is an empty string instead of using isnull() or == None.